# RSS feed for newsletter

Tags: support, rss

I love the newsletters, but would love to receive them in my RSS feed, rather than in my inbox.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, no; looks like [this is the roughly the grand total number of feeds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/151519/175248) which exist and are accessible.

The newsletter has only ever been offered via email anyway, and given that RSS is still fairly niche, it's unlikely that it'd be exposed as an option.